# json2.js JSON.stringify() generates stack overflow when handling a little bigger value

Tags: javascript, json, jscript, wsh

JSON.stringify(value) can not handle just a little bigger value. It makes "stack overflow" error. Is there a workaround?

json2.js is from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

I am running my JavaScript programs on Windows DOS box through cscript.exe (WSH), which is JScript v5.8 on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

I can't find the way to use the, it is said, built-in JSON in JScript v5.8.
So I include the json2.js and it works! 
It works but not very well. JSON.stringify(mydata) generates "Stack overflow" when mydata is just a bit bigger structure.

The way I include json2.js is: 
open json2.js, read entire json2.js into a string ss, eval(ss). Then JSON becomes available and it works.

By the way, I can't see JSON in cscript.exe JScript v5.8, how to enable it?

Comment: Can you clarify "a little bigger"? For example, could you include a sample of your code that generates the stack overflow error?

Comment: Something like this is a cell of an array. The array has about 200 such cells. 
JSON.stringify(words.forth[2]) ==> {"name":"end-code","vid":"forth","wid":2,"creater":["code"],"immediate":true,"compileonly":true,"hel
p":"end-code\t( -- ) Wrap up the new code word."}

If try to stringify the entire array then,
JSON.stringify(words.forth) ==> Stack overflow.

If try to stringify a smaller array, then it's ok,
JSON.stringify(words.wmi) ==> 
[0,{"name":"t/c","vid":"wmi","wid":1,"creater":["colon","(create)"],"help":"t/c\t( -- \"target-compu
ter\" ) wmi.f tools' ... snip ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script engine available via WScript/CScript is the one used in IE7 - so no JSON object as you've already found (and no way to somehow "enable" it).

Most likely reason of stack overflow is attempt to serialize recursive structure instead of proper tree. I don't believe JSON2.js supports such cases. Simple structure with self reference is below (normal `JSON.stringify` fails on it)

```
 var node = { a:"text"};
 node.next = node;
```

Comment: I tried and Yes! JSON.stringify(node) generates 'stack overflow' too. So I'll examine my data first, thank you very very much!!